# How to make a dropdown menu extend past a parent column's width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown with 3 main "categories" inside, and each "category" has several checkboxes (this is being used to filter a search).
Here's an example of my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-3 dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you may have noticed, the dropdown `div` is also a `col-3`.
Basically, I want the dropdown menu to occupy more horizontal space than the `col-3` (like `text-nowrap` does with simple text inside a `div`).
Here's an example of what I want it to look like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @WebDevBooster Here it is

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't get why are you applying `col-3` to the drop-down itself? I mean, the width remains the same either way, doesn't it? The width of the drop-down is determined by the text you put inside.

Comment: @Aydin It looks like the 1st snippet, and I want it to look like the 2nd snippet, while keeping the `col-3` class

Comment: @WebDevBooster The `col-3` class is there for design purposes and can't be altered, because before this I have a `<div class="col-9">`.

Comment: My point is that this particular `col-3` doesn't actually affect the width of the button.

Comment: The button will simply overflow the column if it's not wide enough. So, your `col-3` has no effect on the button.

Comment: @WebDevBooster You're right, but even if I remove the `col-3` class, I still have a `col-9` at the left of the `button` (in my code), wich is the same as having this `col-3`. So to simplify the question I just wrote a `col-3` class there, instead of explaining I have a `col-9` behind

Comment: @AndréPereira try this CSS line: .dropdown { position:initial; }
I'll write a proper answer if that does the job for you.

Comment: @Aydin Yes, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap applies `position:relative` to the `.dropdown` class. If you want the child element of the dropdown to extend beyond the dropdown, then add a class to the dropdown to override `position:relative`. Here I have added the `.extended` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
     .extended {
         position: initial !important;
     }
</style>
<div class="col-3 dropdown extended">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```